Multirow Text Missing When Using \columncolor in LaTeX Table
In this code text "April " is not coming if I use multirow. Without multirow, it is working well.

{\large
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9EAD3}}l|>{\columncolor[HTML]{F4CCCC}}l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{April }}} & \textbf{abc} \\
& University  \\
\cline{2-2}
& \textbf{Supervisor:} Prof.  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}



As said in Issue with coloring multirow cells, you can use \multirow{-3} instead of \multirow{3}:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

{\large
\begin{tabular}{|>{\color{blue}\columncolor[HTML]{D9EAD3}}l|>{\columncolor[HTML]{F4CCCC}}l|}
\hline
& \textbf{abc} \\
& University  \\
\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{{April}}} & \textbf{Supervisor:} Prof.  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}



An alternative could be using tabularray:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{acolor}{HTML}{D9EAD3}
\definecolor{bcolor}{HTML}{F4CCCC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    column{1}={bg=acolor},
    column{2}={bg=bcolor},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries},
    hline{1,Z}={}, 
    vlines,
    cmd={\large},
    }
\SetCell[r=3]{fg=blue} April & abc \\
& University  \\
& \textbf{Supervisor:} Prof. \\
\end{tblr}%
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and its built-in command \Block.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

{\large
\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\color{blue}\columncolor[HTML]{D9EAD3}}l|>{\columncolor[HTML]{F4CCCC}}l|}
\Hline
\Block{3-1}{\textbf{April}} 
& \textbf{abc} \\
& University  \\
& \textbf{Supervisor:} Prof.  \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}

You need several compilations.

